# How to prevent Chrome on Android from auto-scaling the page?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scaling, zooming

I have a web app which can display images at various sizes. One selection is to scale up to the size of the screen (and then scroll to it so that nothing else is visible). When I do that, the browser automatically zooms out to fit the entire image plus the rest of the page. How do I prevent that automatic scaling, while still allowing the user to zoom in and out?

Comment: Are you applying the `<meta type="viewport">` tag with the appropriate content? MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I have: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Comment: Do you also include the `initial-scale` ?